# LLVM assertion error when getting the instruction pointer

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I'm trying to get the pointer to each instruction, which supposedly can be achieved by doing:

```
Value* ptr = dyn_cast<Value>(&inst);
```

However, I keep getting a segmentation fault when running the compiled C++ program with cmake. In debug mode, I get the following error message:

```
opt-11: /usr/lib/llvm-11/include/llvm/IR/User.h:170: llvm::Value* llvm::User::getOperand(unsigned int) 
const: Assertion `i < NumUserOperands && "getOperand() out of range!"' failed.
```

In [LLVM doc](https://llvm.org/doxygen/User_8h_source.html), here is the block of code that points to the source of the assertion:

```
   Value *getOperand(unsigned i) const {
     assert(i < NumUserOperands && "getOperand() out of range!");
     return getOperandList()[i];
   }
```

I added empty check to every variable acquired from `getOperand()` in the program but the error remains. Does anyone know why it's happening and how to fix it?

Comment: 1. Run Valgrind. 2. If you want to do a lot with LLVM, build a tree with debug symbols.

Comment: And FWIW, using `dyn_cast<>` to cast to `Value` doesn't make sense. `Value` is the root class. If you have an `Instruction*` you already have `Value*`, there's nothing left for `dyn_cast<>` to do.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I'm new to debugging in C++, can you elaborate on building a tree with the debug symbol?

Comment: You are right, previously I thought the source of my problem was at the instruction pointer but it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, some instructions in the LLVM IR had only one operand and it would not make sense to get the second one with `inst.getOperand(1)`. Therefore it is necessary to check the number of operands before proceeding:

```
         for (auto& inst : bb) {
            Value* v1;
            Value* v2;
            if (inst.getNumOperands() >= 1) 
                v1 = inst.getOperand(0);
            if (inst.getNumOperands() == 2)
                v2 = inst.getOperand(1);
         }
```

or simply

```
         for (auto& inst : bb) {
            Value* v1 = inst.getOperand(0);
            Value* v2;
            if (inst.getNumOperands() == 2)
                v2 = inst.getOperand(1);
         }
```